# Do I have to pay taxes in the US if I work remotely for company in other country and pay taxes there?

Tags: usa, taxes, working, russia

I'm going to move in the US soon to work for US employer and live there. But I also have clients in other countries (Russia in particular, I'm Russian citizen) and they are paying all the taxes for me locally.

I've read something about double-taxation, but couldn't find information that would answer my questions. Once I'm in the US should I pay taxes for that income there as well? Or what options do I have?

Comment: Most countries tax by resdience.  Any work you do when you are physically present in the US is subject to US taxation.  If you spend enough time in the country, you will become a resident (for the purpose of taxation, at least), and your worldwide income will be subject to tax.  You may be able to benefit from credits for taxes paid to other jurisdictions.  Also, if you're living in the US, you're not resident in Russia, and you may no longer need to pay income tax there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the relevant article: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-tax-credit

Basically, you reduce the amount of taxes you owe in the US for that foreign income by the amount of tax you paid to the foreign country. So, if Russia charges you $100.00 tax on the income, and the US Tax calculation is that you owe $100.00, then you will take the credit and owe nothing.